# DevOps API - C# Retrieve list of Projects using Client Libraries

Tags: c#, api, devops

I am trying to get [THIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/rest/samples?view=azure-devops#net-client-libraries) example to work (.Net Client Libraries example) - however everything I have attempted results in an error:

> Basic authentication requires a secure connection to the server.

There is another example using the REST Api at the top of the page I linked and this works perfectly fine. For some reason, I just cant get this working using the libraries!

My code looks like this:

```
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://adtfs:8080/tfs/{MyCompany}");
            string personalAccessToken = "MyPATString";
            VssBasicCredential credentials = new VssBasicCredential("", personalAccessToken);

            using (ProjectHttpClient projectHttpClient = new ProjectHttpClient(uri, credentials))
            {
                IEnumerable<TeamProjectReference> projects = projectHttpClient.GetProjects().Result;
            }
```

As I mentioned, using the same URL and PAT in the REST API example works fine, but for the libraries, I just cant get beyond the error mentioned above.

Am I missing something or can anyone suggest anything else I could try please?

Comment: It's probably not, but could you change, http=>https from [http://adtfs:8080/tfs/{MyCompany}](http://adtfs:8080/tfs/{MyCompany}) to [https://adtfs:8080/tfs/{MyCompany}](https://adtfs:8080/tfs/{MyCompany})

Comment: @GI1 actually it's almost certainly that. The "requires a secure connection" bit means HTTPS instead of HTTP.

Comment: That seems to have done it - thank you! Feel free to add in as an answer! I am now getting another error now (The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.) and this occurs also when trying the REST API example with Https. I will investigate this separately. Feel free to update with an answer for me to accept.

Comment: The handshake in https is connected to the SSL certificate, but I could be mistaking, so possible that the client isn't working cause of some badly setup SSL certificate on the server or you setup a self-signed one that isn't trusted by your machine running the client yet? *just taking another guess sorry*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change http=>https from http://adtfs:8080/tfs/{MyCompany} to https://adtfs:8080/tfs/{MyCompany} ... easiest answer there was I guess works glad it helped ... but just as precautionary tale, I'll add this for posterity, you should use https anyways if the server supports it (had an app that was working sometimes slow, sometimes fast and I couldn't figure out why until I saw this https://httpvshttps.com, turns out the https tunnel was always being recreated cause I put http instead of https and the server was set to always switch to https).

Comment: Thanks again for that! I was using an old URL as we do also have a https that I am now using and works fine! Cheers for the headsup!